# Discrete mathematics: Contrapositive proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm doing a problem that asks me to prove by contrapositive:

for all x,y that are elements of the real positive numbers,

```
      if x != y, then x + y > (4xy)/(x + y)
```

The contrapositive is simple, I end up with

```
      if x + y < (4xy)/(x+y), then x = y
```

I'm confused where to go from here, at first I said if x = y then x+y is equivalent to 2x, and x*y is equivalent to x^2. Simplifying this although leaves me with 2x > 2x.

I would like someone to show me where I made a mistake and/or what I need to do to prove this.

Comment: You haven't stated the contrapositive of the original statement correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go over that again now.

Comment: The negation of $a > b$ is $a \le b$.

Comment: Thus, if $x+y \le \frac {(4xy)} {(x+y)}$, i.e. $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy \le 4xy$ (because $x+y$ positive) and thus $x^2+y^2 -2xy=(x-y)^2 \le 0$.

Comment: ^ answer listed above